# Automatic connection to Hive or Impala servers in Tableau

Tags: hive, cloudera, tableau-api, impala

I was wondering if anyone managed to automatically connect to Hive(Hive2) or Impala servers? Currently I have to manually type all the info when I run a new Tableau session and it is a bit annoying.

Also I am using Cloudera ODBC drivers.

Cheers!

Comment: Are you talking about Tableau Server or Tableau Desktop?

Comment: Desktop version. I know that it is doable if I save the workspace, but want to see if I can do it as soon as Tableau starts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do is: connect to the datasource in Tableau and then save the file (without creating any visualizations). Then whenever you want to create a visualization from your Hive data just open up that file and save it as a new name and create something.

Comment: I would accept it, but that is not the exactly I am doing right now. Was looking if it is possible in settings to tweak this.